# Why does my Visual Studio not show a solution in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#

I am new to Visual Studio. I have been working on some training videos and when I create an console application I see the console application name but no solution example. How can I create the solution so that I can add multiple projects underneath the solution.

Screen Shot: (Screen Shot from my Visual Studio)

[image]

Screen Shot: (Screen Shot from the instruction WebSite)

[image]

I need my Visual Studio to look like this.

**Question: Why is my Visual Studio not producing a solution?**

Created a project: Console Application and there is not solution. Is this a toggle switch some places.

[image]

Comment: This may sound like a daft question, but have you opened the solution itself? (File -> Open ..)

Comment: do you have a solution open?

Comment: @matt_lethargic Creating a new project should automatically create a solution file.

Comment: How do you create just a solution? That might be a good starting point.

Comment: Same as most Windows applications - File > New...

Comment: Yeah, I thought that it was File - New and then select which type of windows application you want to create. Like in this case a Console Application. I see the ConsoleApplication1 but no solution name. Is there a setting that turns this on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new solution by going to File -> New -> Project:

[image: File -> New]

Then choose the type of project you want:

[image: Choose Project Type]

Solution with new project appears:

[image: Solution with new project]

Comment: Tried that I get the WpfApplication3 but no Solution. Is my Visual Studio set differently.

Comment: When selecting a project, go to Other Project Types -> Visual Studio Solutions -> Blank Solution

Comment: Yes, thank you. It showed a solution but then when i right clicked and added a project the solution disappeared.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Mark the "Always show solution" checkbox